# Css themes that make an html page look like the android UI?

Tags: android, themes

Are there any css themes that look like the Android UI?  I would like to use HTML to quickly mockup/prototype Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

for creating wireframes, you can use any of the available icon packs, and for mockup apps in HTML you can use sencha touch framework. It has the android.css file which will solve your purpose.